# Postgres with RoR and Heroku not showing nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have moved a site from development to testing on Heroku, and thus switched from sqlite to Postgres.  I am getting an error with one of the lines of code, and am not sure why it doesn't work in Postgres.

The code is:

```
Vendor.where.not(upload_key: "11242015213724")
```

This should display a list of Vendors whose upload_key is nil, however, it results in zero records.

However, if i search by:

```
Vendor.where(upload_key: nil)
```

I do get the correct result.  Is there something I am missing in PostGres that doesn't allow the records with a nil upload_key to be displayed in the first statement?

Thanks!

Comment: You've learned the hard way it's recommended to use matching dbs in dev and production.

Comment: Def a great motto to code by!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
Vendor.where("upload_key != ? OR upload_key is ?", "11242015213724", nil)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, was hoping for a way to do it without checking for nil separately.